# How to convert from text to JSON using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I want to convert a text file to JSON, but in a very particular way. My text file looks like this:

```
Data 1:
datapoint1-1 = 21
datapoint1-2 = 23
Data 2:
datapoint2-1 = 21
datapoint2-2 = 23
datapoint2-3 = 23
```

I want to create a JSON file that separates this data like this:

```
{
 {
 "Data": "1",
 "Datapoints": [
   {
    "datapoint1-1": "21",
    "datapoint1-2": "23"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
 "Data": "2",
 "Datapoints": [
  {
   "datapoint2-1": "21",
   "datapoint2-2": "23",
   "datapoint2-3": "23"
  }
 ]
 }
}
```

My first step has split the data into 2 arrays inside an array. The first array is `Data 1` plus its data-points and the second is `Data 2` plus its data-points.

Now I am stuck on how I can convert those arrays into the JSON format I want. Does anyone have an idea? or can direct me in the right direction for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I haven't found anything helpful. Only thing I've tried is a simple JSON.stringify(obj) but it isn't specific enough to what I want as an outcome.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` tend to convert text format (those are like json format) to proper json format.

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid javascript or JSON. Is that supposed to be an array or an object? And why is `Datapoints` an array if it's always just going to have one item?

Comment: I made it into an array because I thought it'd be easier to use in my code, in case I want to reference a specific data point.

Comment: Thanks either way. I will try something different and come up with a better question if I come across one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution

```
const input = `
  Data 1:
  datapoint1-1 = 21
  datapoint1-2 = 23
  Data 2:
  datapoint2-1 = 21
  datapoint2-2 = 23
  datapoint2-3 = 23
`

const array = input.split('\n').reverse()
const response = []
let template = {}
template['Datapoints'] = []
let switcher = false

array.map(arr => {
  // remove empty strings
  if (arr) {
    if (arr.includes('datapoint')) {
      const keyValue = arr.split(' = ')
      template.Datapoints.push({ [`${keyValue[0]}`]: keyValue[1] })
    } else {
      const keyValue = arr.split(' ')
      template.Datapoints.reverse()

      template[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1].slice(0, -1)
      switcher = true
    }

    if (switcher) {
      response.push(template)
      template = {}
      template['Datapoints'] = []
      switcher = false
    }
  }
})

const finalResponse = response.reverse()

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResponse, null, 2))
```

and in console you got

```
[
  {
    "Datapoints": [
      {
        "datapoint1-1": "21"
      },
      {
        "datapoint1-2": "23"
      }
    ],
    "Data": "1"
  },
  {
    "Datapoints": [
      {
        "datapoint2-1": "21"
      },
      {
        "datapoint2-2": "23"
      },
      {
        "datapoint2-3": "23"
      }
    ],
    "Data": "2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**To convert text files in JSON you can use the JACKSON OBJECT MAPPER jar in your code. Create a simple POJO. It will read JSON string from a file and map it to your class.
Then you would need to convert the JSON string value to java object. This will help you with the same.**

Comment: Hi there, the question specifically asks for NodeJs solution (not a java one).